# Help with a rewrite rule

Tags: iis, isapi-rewrite

I have the following RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^?.]+)$ /MyPage.aspx\?Name=$1 [NC,L]
```

Which works fine when my URL is: http://www.somedomain.com/Tony

I get the following result: `/MyPage.aspx?Name=Tony` but I need to change it so it works with this type of URL: http://www.somedomain.com/MemberPages/Tony

Can someone tell me what the Regexp should be, Unfortunately, I am not very good with Regular Expressions so any help is appreciated.

Thank you,

Tony

Comment: Where should http://www.somedomain.com/MemberPages/Tony redirect to, MyPage.aspx?Name=MemberPages/Tony?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to optionally allow `MemberPages/`, you can do it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/(MemberPages\/)?([^?.]+)$ /MyPage.aspx\?Name=$2 [NC,L]
```

`?` means optionally include the preceding element, even if that element is a full capture group like `(MemberPages/)`. Then you have to change the back-reference to `$2` to account for the additional capture group.

So this rule will work for both urls:

```
http://www.somedomain.com/Tony
http://www.somedomain.com/MemberPages/Tony
```

Will both go to:

```
/MyPage.aspx?Name=Tony
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for any second-level path:

RewriteRule ^/[^/]+/([^?.]+)$ /MyPage.aspx\?Name=$1 [NC,L]

This will work for /MemberPages/-prefixed paths

RewriteRule ^/MemberPages/([^?.]+)$ /MyPage.aspx\?Name=$1 [NC,L]